# Why gcov will cause program crash?

Tags: gcc, gcov

I am using the `gcov` to test my program (add "`-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`") on `Linux`, but the program will crash after start:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000034e433386f in __strlen_sse42 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000053c57a in __gcov_init ()
#2  0x000000000053c4b9 in _GLOBAL__I_65535_0_g_st_rerun_cmd_param ()
    at source/rerun/aicent_ara_rerun.c:963
#3  0x000000000053dc26 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#4  0x0000000000403743 in _init ()
#5  0x00007fff6d6b3ce8 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000000053db55 in __libc_csu_init ()
#7  0x00000034e421ecb0 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000404449 in _start ()
```

From __gcov_init() source (http://www.coreboot.org/~stepan/coreboot-coverage/lib/libgcov.c.gcov.html) ,

```
......
size_t filename_length = strlen(info->filename);
......
```

I can see the root cause is the "`info->filename`" is invalid (After disassembling the code, the address is `0x57c4ac00000000`, and it is indeed invalid).

I don't know how to analyse this bug, could anyone give any clues? Thanks very much in advance!

P.S. My `Linux` environment:

```
[root@localhost rel_1_3_3_20140902]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`gcc` version:

```
[root@localhost rel_1_3_3_20140902]# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is using `-fpack-struct=4` compile option on 64-bit Linux. For detailed information, we can refer https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43341.